# Mixed hash not working correctly

Tags: perl, hash

I'm creating this hash

```
    my %obj_cuentascontables = {
        '4210' => {
            'banderamayor' => 'true',
            'enlace' => 'true',
            'not_rlike_nombre' => 'DEVOLUCION'
    },
        '4410' => {
            'banderamayor' => 'true',
            'enlace' => 'true',
            'rlike_nombre' => 'DEVOLUCION',
            'categoria_cuenta' => 'DEVOLUCIONES REBAJAS Y DESCUENTOS'
        }
};

my %param = {
         'concepto_ID' => "$concepto_ID",
         'formato_ID' => $formato_ID,
         'obj_cuentascontables'=> { %obj_cuentascontables },
};
```

And later I Dump `%param` and i get this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'concepto_ID' => '5501',
          'formato_ID' => 1001,
          'obj_cuentascontables' => {
                                      'HASH(0xf16eb70)' => undef
                                    }
        };
```

I can't use that 'HASH' Thing, so, i was trying to see if i was referencing incorrectly the hash and i create another one very similar.

```
my %obj_cuentascontables = ();
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4210'}{'banderamayor'} = 'true';
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4210'}{'enlace'} = 'true';
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4210'}{'not_rlike_nombre'} = 'DEVOLUCION';
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4410'}{'banderamayor'} = 'true';
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4410'}{'enlace'} = 'true';
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4410'}{'rlike_nombre'} = 'DEVOLUCION';
    $obj_cuentascontables{'4410'}{'categoria_cuenta'} = 'DEVOLUCIONES REBAJAS Y DESCUENTOS';

    my %param = ();
    $param{'concepto_ID'}= $concepto_ID;
    $param{'formato_ID'} = $formato_ID;
    $param{'obj_cuentascontables'} = \%obj_cuentascontables;
```

And then Dumper return this:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'concepto_ID' => 5501,
          'formato_ID' => 1001,
          'obj_cuentascontables' => {
                                      '4410' => {
                                                  'enlace' => 'true',
                                                  'rlike_nombre' => 'DEVOLUCION',
                                                  'categoria_cuenta' => 'DEVOLUCIONES REBAJAS Y DESCUENTOS',
                                                  'banderamayor' => 'true'
                                                },
                                      '4210' => {
                                                  'enlace' => 'true',
                                                  'not_rlike_nombre' => 'DEVOLUCION',
                                                  'banderamayor' => 'true'
                                                }
                                    }
        };
```

My question is, WHY?!!!... I want the second Dump in my first structure... It is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Always use `use strict; use warnings;`! The latter would have identified the error.

```
$ perl -e'use strict; use warnings; my %obj_cuentascontables = { };'
Reference found where even-sized list expected at -e line 1.
```

You are assigning a hash reference to a list when it expects a list of scalars to use as keys and values. Keep in mind that

```
{ ... }
```

is roughly

```
do { my %anon = ( ... ); \%anon }
```

so

```
my %obj_cuentascontables = { ... };
```

should be

```
my %obj_cuentascontables = ( ... );
```

Answer (score 5):

If you look carefully at how you constructed the hash in the first snippet, you used curly braces `{}`. In the context of your assignment, this is assigning a hash reference to your hash.

What you need are round brackets `()`:

```
my %obj_cuentascontables = (
    '4210' => {
            'banderamayor' => 'true',
            'enlace' => 'true',
            'not_rlike_nombre' => 'DEVOLUCION'
    },
    '4410' => {
            'banderamayor' => 'true',
            'enlace' => 'true',
            'rlike_nombre' => 'DEVOLUCION',
            'categoria_cuenta' => 'DEVOLUCIONES REBAJAS Y DESCUENTOS'
    }
);
```

---

This is why you should `use warnings;`, as it would warn you about this:

```
Reference found where even-sized list expected ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using `use warnings;` which would have helped you see the odd-number error.

I assume you want your `$param{obj_cuentascontables}` to point to the hash `%obj_cuentascontables`. That way, you can refer to:

```
$param{obj_cuentascontables}->{4210}->{banderamayor}
```

as having the value of `true`.

You need to assign a *reference* to your `%obj_cuentascontables` hash for the value of the `obj_cuentascontables` key in your `%param` hash.

```
my %param = {
         concepto_ID          => "$concepto_ID",
         formato_ID           => $formato_ID,
         obj_cuentascontables => \%obj_cuentascontables,
};
```

My preference is to use the `->` syntax when referring to references. Officially, these are both the same:

```
$param{obj_cuentascontables}->{4210}->{banderamayor}
$param{obj_cuentascontables}{4210}{banderamayor}
```

However, I find that using the `->` syntax reminds me this is not really a hash, but a *reference* to a hash. This helps me get the syntax right when I build these complex data structures.

What you did was similar to this:

```
my $hash_address = sprintf "%s", \%obj_cuentascontables; # Stingifying the hash reference
$param{obj_cuentascontables} = { };
$param{obj_cuentascontables} = { $hash_address => };     # Not 100% Perl will parse this...
```

You assigned a hash reference to `$param{obj_cuentascontables}` which is what you want, but you then used the address of the hash as the key, and no value.